# Create X-Ray Shortcut

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, edit-mode

How do I create a shortcut for this command?

**`view3DShading.show_xray`**

[image: this button]

Answer (score 3):

### Alt + Z

You can find or change this in your preferences by navigating to Edit > Preferences > Keymap > Search

[image]
[image]

Before setting a new keybind, make sure it isn't in use by another function!

Comment: Thank you thankyouthankyou SO much.  I mean, I went into the keymap and searched for it and didn't find it, but I think I must have typed in x-ray insead of xray.  Still, THANKS!  That will make things SOO much easier, now!

Comment: @Krayne No problem! Just make sure to mark this post as answered :)